# Ruby scripts with access to Rails Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scripting

Where and how do I run a simple script that uses my rails environment. Specifically I have one column that holds multiple pieces of information, I've added columns now for each piece of information and need to run a ruby script that can run to call a method on each row of the database to extrapolate data and save it to the new column.

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't/shouldn't use a migration to store and execute that code?

Comment: no. I dont know how to do it. This is something I like to be able to test before running, so I write these scripts in parts.. show me the objects im going to affect - ill limit to 200 first, then Ill execute it. This is a table with 2million+ rows, so i dont want to just run a migration because if it fails i have to truncate, and re-import. there goes 30 minutes.

Comment: 5 years later I feel even more strongly that Rake task is the way to go. check my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31738018/726239

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to agree with David here. Use a migration for this. I'm not sure what you want to do, but running it from inside your environment is much, *much* more efficient then loading up the app environment manually. And since your initial post suggests you're only doing this once, a migration is the way to go:

`rails g migration MigrateData`

.. generates:

```
class MigrateData < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    # Your migration code here
  end

  def self.down
    # Rollback scenario
  end
end
```

Of course, you will *always* want to perform this locally first, using some test data.

Comment: You can just put ruby code in the up and down methods of a migration?

Comment: Of course! A migration is run from within the environment using rake. You can load up any model you like.

Comment: So, I can't think of one off the top of my head, but I know I have needed it in the past, If this wasnt/isnt a data migration, would you just suggest using a rake task? Seems like there would be an easy way to just 'play' with my data/models without formally placing them in functional code.

Comment: Sorry about the late response, but for completeness: yes, I would suggest you do this using a rake task if it's something that repeats itself. For instance, if you want to execute some kind of end of month command, you can do that in a rake task and even execute it using a cronjob.

Answer (score 9):

Using a migration sounds like the right way to go if I am understanding your use case.

However, if you really do want to write a standalone script that needs access to your Rails application's models, you can `require` the `environment.rb` file from inside your standalone script.

Example:

```
#!/bin/env ruby

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "production" # Set to your desired Rails environment name
require '/path/to/railsapp/config/environment.rb'

# After this point you have access to your models and other classes from your Rails application

model_instance = MyModel.find(7)
model_instance.some_attribute = "new value"
model_instance.save
```

Comment: from within my lib folder, I get `require': no such file to load -- /path/to/railsapp/config/environment.rb (LoadError) when using this method..

Comment: You need to replace that path with the path to your `config/environment.rb` file.

Comment: my apologies, had too many things going on, lazy copy and paste.

Answer (score 6):

Agree with everyone, for this specific case it sounds like migration will be way to go, however, to do this regularly, or write some other task/script that interacts rails app environment make rails generate a rake task for you! This gets saved with your rails app, and can be run again and again :)

Easiest way to generate a rake task that interact with rails app/models is to make Rails generate Rake tasks for you!! :)

Here's an example

1. run `rails g task my_namespace my_task`
2. This will generate a file called `lib/tasks/my_namespace.rake` which looks like:

```ruby
namespace :my_namespace do
desc "TODO: Describe your task here"
  task :my_task1 => :environment do
    #write any ruby code here and also work with your models
    puts User.find(1).name
  end
end
```

3. Run this task with `rake my_namespace:my_task`
4. Watch your ruby code task that interacts with rails modal run!

Answer (score 1):

Seeding data:

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

Adding data with migrations

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Working with Rake Tasks

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks

I prefer to use migrations for adding some data in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-time thing, use a migration.

If this is something that needs to be done multiple times, use a rake task for it.

Comment: Where and how...  this doesn't answer the question at all. How do i execute ruby in a migration.

Comment: @Rabbott agree with David,  check my answer on details of how to write a rake task that interacts with the application.