# RoR: 'NameError Exception: uninitialized constant Address' when trying to access recently added data from a populated postgresql table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-connection

I have created a *Ruby* script that inserts data into a *PostgreSQL* database. The db exists and so do the tables.

I have an `Address` model and a `Company` model in my app and those two are connected through a one-to-one relationship (`address_id` referenced in companies table). I have run the script and populated the address table without any problems but when the scripts gets to where the existing recently saved address ids are read from database (`Address.pluck(:id)`), I get the error.

The address records are saved in the database as I can see in the *pgAdmin* but it looks like the script does not recognize that I want to read from table. I would appreciate any help.

Here is a fraction of the script that is relevant:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'securerandom'
require 'active_record'
require 'logger'
require 'csv'

DB_YML = "./config/database.yml"

RAILS_ENV = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development"
db_config = {}
if File.exist?(DB_YML)
  settings = YAML.load_file(DB_YML)
  if settings and settings.include?(RAILS_ENV)
    db_config["database"] = settings[RAILS_ENV]
    puts db_config
  end
else
  raise "database.yml not found!"
end

# Establish connection to the DB based on the 'development'.
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_config["database"])
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)


ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

address_inserts = []

CSV.foreach("script/addresses.csv") do  |row|
    line1 = row[0].strip
    line2 = row[1] unless row[1]=='nil'
    postcode = row[2] unless row[2]=='nil'
    city = row[3]
    county = row[4]

    address_inserts << "('#{line1}', "+ (line2 ? "'#{line2}'" : "null") + ", " + (postcode ? "'#{postcode}'" : "null") +
    ", '#{city}', '#{county}', now(), now())"
end

unless address_inserts.empty?
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO addresses (line1, line2,\
postcode, city, county, created_at, updated_at) VALUES #{address_inserts.join(', ')}")
  #print "INSERT INTO addresses (line1, line2, postcode, city, county,created_at, updated_at) VALUES #{address_inserts.join(", ")}"
end
puts "________________________________________________________________________"
puts "addresses done"
end
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  companies_inserts = []
  address_ids = Address.pluck(:id)

  CSV.foreach("script/companies.csv") do  |row|
    company_name = row[0].strip
    fax_number = row[1] unless row[1]=='nil'
    phone_number = row[2] unless row[2]=='nil'
    reg_number = row[3]
    address_id = address_ids.pop

    companies_inserts << "('#{company_name}, '#{fax_number}','#{phone_number}',\
'#{reg_number}', #{address_id}, now(), now())"
  end
  unless companies_inserts.empty?
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO companies (company_name, fax_number,\
    phone_number, reg_number, address_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES #{companies_inserts.join(", ")}")
    #print "INSERT INTO companies (company_name, fax_number,phone_number, reg_number, address_id,\
    #created_at, updated_at) VALUES #{companies_inserts.join(", ")}"
  end
  puts "________________________________________________________________________"
  puts "companies done"
end
```

****UPDATE****

solved by adding 
    require './config/environment.rb'
to the script.

Comment: If I understood correctly, it's a standalone script? You need to declare an `Address` class and inherit it from `ActiveRecord::Base`. In your script, I would put this declaration after your logger initialization. Otherwise, Ruby cannot know what an `Address` is.

Comment: I placed that script in the scripts folder but yes it is standalone. I just found a solution to this at the very moment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942281/ruby-scripts-with-access-to-rails-models. I had to require my environment.rb file. Thanks anyways Yanis :)